# Программа для записи видео с рабочего стола в Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu

Ищу программу для записи видео, и записи голоса с микрофона, с рабочего стола в Ubuntu 13.10. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kazam и RecordMyDesktop